# Sql injection strings dataset (for ML)

Tags: sql-injection

I'm looking for a dataset that contains sql injection attack strings. Have you ever seen one?

I need it in order to train a machine learning classifier.

Comment: If this was off topic, why wasn't it migrated to StackOverflow? Are the moderators attempting to imply the question would also be off topic there? Was this question closed for objective or political reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This github repo contains SQL Injection attack strings, plus every other security related list you could ever want:

https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists

The SQL Injection stuff is in the `Fuzzing` directory.